# JQuery animate top and left same time (jumping & running)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a very simple 2D game where you run forward automatically and then jump at keypress to avoid obstacles along the course.

I made this so far. The only issue is that jumping "stops" the forward-motion. And if you for example hold the up button it stops the entire game and you keep flying upwards like a bird...

Can anyone give me some advice on how to fix it? I would also LOVE it if someone could guide me in how to place 1-2 random obstacles along the course and restart the game, also show total position left traveled if those obstacles are hit by the user.

My plan is to speed up the game every time you finish a course!

Thanks a lot in advance :)

```
<div style='' id='map'></div>

$(function(){
var unjump = function(){
        $('#player').stop().animate({
            bottom: '33'
        });
}
var jump = function(){
        $('#player').stop().animate({
            bottom: '+=100'
        }); 
setTimeout(unjump, 1000);
}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 38: // up
        jump();
        break;
    }
});

var player = '<div id="player"></div>';
$("#map").append(player);
function run(){
var position = $('#player').position();
var width = $('#map').width();
if (position.left > width){
$("#player").css( "left", 0 );
}
        $('#player').stop().animate({
            left: '+=200'
        });
}       
run = setInterval(run, 100);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://fiddle.jshell.net/s0wtjtk7/1/)

the main error was in css positioning of player

**css code**

```
#player{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border:solid;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
#map{
    position:relative;
}
```

**html code**

```
<div style='border:solid ;height:100px' id='map'></div>
```

**js code**

```
var interval = null;
var interval2 = null;

$(function () {

    var player = '<div id="player"></div>';
    $("#map").append(player);

    var unjump = function () {
        $('#player').stop().animate({
            bottom: '0'
        });
    };
    var jump = function () {
        $('#player').stop().animate({
            bottom: '+=100'
        }, 500);
          interval2 = setTimeout(unjump, 500);
    };
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        switch (e.which) {
            case 38: // up
                jump();
                break;
        }
    });


    function run() {

        var width = $('#map').width();
        if ($('#player').position().left > width) {
            $("#player").css("left", 0);
        }
        $('#player').stop().animate({
            left: '+=10'
        });
    }
    interval = setInterval(run, 500);

});
```

Comment: The issue remains if you lower the setInterval, and if you hold up button you still fly like a bird and game stops :(

Comment: of course  it will. Add some jump height limit check

Comment: Alright. But still, if I lower the setinterval to say 100. Jumping stops working completely. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/u8deLxkz/2/

Main issue was to perform run animation only if no other animation is running.
Except for that, I tidied up the code a little.

```
$(function(){
    //No need for two separate functions, left is handled here as well
    function jump(){
        $('#player').animate({
            bottom: '+=30',
            left: '+=10'
        },100).animate({
            bottom: '-=30',
            left: '+=10'
        },100);             
    }
    //I think keyup gives better results
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        switch(e.which) {               
                case 38: //up
                jump();
                break;
            }
        });
    var player = '<div id="player" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: blue; position:absolute; bottom:500px;"></div>';
    $("#map").append(player);
    function run(){
        var position = $('#player').position();
        var width = $('#map').width();
        $('#player').position()
        console.log('pos ' + position.left + "\nwidth: " + width);
        if (position.left > width){
            $("#player").finish();
            $("#player").css( "left", 0 );
        }
        //Continue with horizontal animation only if jumping is not in progress
        if(!$('#player').is(':animated') ){             
            $('#player').animate({
                left: '+=10'
            },100);
        }
    }       
    var go = setInterval(run, 100);
});
```

Comment: Hmm.. make sure you click the gray div before hitting up button, it should work